# Payload for "onProgress" callback exceeds $ 5120 bytes limit

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk

As part of a revit addin that I am running in design automation, I need to extract some data from the file, send it in json format to an external server for analysis, and get the result to update my revit file with new features. I was able to satisfy my requirement by following the indicated in: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/communicate-servers-inside-design-automation, which worked as I needed, the problem arises when the size of the data to send for the analysis grows, it results in the following error:

```
[11/12/2020 07:54:08] Error: Payload for "onProgress" callback exceeds $ 5120 bytes limit.
```

When checking my data it turns out that the payload is around 27000 bytes, are there other ways to send data from design automation for Payloads larger than 5120 bytes?

I was unable to find documentation related to the use of ACESAPI: acesHttpOperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way at the moment to send data from your work item to another server.

So either you would have to split up the data into multiple 5120 byte parts and send them like that or have two work items: one for getting the data from the file before doing the analysis and one for updating the file afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Adam, i´m actually migrating from a two scripts approach to this one with external connection for the analize. I need the script answer asap, so, the two scripts approach is good, but with big files, the time lose by upload / download and starting workitem slow  down my solution.  Just now, i ended and test the payload split and my results are faster than with two scripts.